# How to accurately determine ST_Intersects of point and geography near boundaries (ST_Intersects geography vs. geometry discrepancy)

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

I have a `geography` column of polygons. This column has been `ST_Subdivide`d for point-in-polygon lookup performance.

When I perform an `ST_Intersects` between a point < 10m from the edge of a polygon with a `geography` type, I get `false`. But after casting to `geometry` types, I get `true`:

```sql
SELECT
ST_Intersects(ST_GeogFromText('POINT(-118.46131 34.31171)'), latlong_shape) AS intersects_geog,
ST_Intersects(ST_GeogFromText('POINT(-118.46131 34.31171)')::geometry, latlong_shape::geometry) AS intersects_geom
FROM region_ids_for_latlong_shapes
WHERE ST_Distance(ST_GeogFromText('POINT(-118.46131 34.31171)'), latlong_shape) < 10;

| intersects_geog | intersects_geom |
| --------------- | --------------- |
| false           | true            |
| false           | false           |
```

I'm aware that there are expected differences between `ST_Intersects(geography, geography)` and `ST_Intersects(geometry, geometry)`, but I don't understand why they would be occurring in this instance:

- The geometries are valid
- Even if it were some great circle discrepancy, I'd expect the point to be intersecting one of the polygons, not outside both of them.

**What is the most accurate way to determine which polygon this point intersects?** I understand I *can* cast to `geometry` types, but I'm surprised that `ST_Intersect`'s `geography` support isn't working here. Is there to do this accurately without casting?

Here is the point and the two closest shapes:

[image: Overview image]

[image: Zoomed in to point and boundary]

Some more diagnostics:

```sql
SELECT
ST_Intersects(ST_GeogFromText('POINT(-118.46131 34.31171)'), latlong_shape) AS geogs_intersect,
ST_Intersects(ST_GeogFromText('POINT(-118.46131 34.31171)')::geometry, latlong_shape::geometry) AS geoms_intersect,
ST_IsValid(latlong_shape::geometry) AS geom_isvalid,
ST_Relate(ST_GeogFromText('POINT(-118.46131 34.31171)')::geometry, latlong_shape::geometry) AS relate_geoms,
ST_Distance(ST_GeogFromText('POINT(-118.46131 34.31171)'), latlong_shape) AS geogs_distance,
ST_Distance(ST_GeogFromText('POINT(-118.46131 34.31171)'), latlong_shape, false) AS geogs_no_spheroid_distance,
ST_Distance(ST_GeogFromText('POINT(-118.46131 34.31171)')::geometry, latlong_shape::geometry) AS geoms_distance,
ST_3DDistance(ST_GeogFromText('POINT(-118.46131 34.31171)')::geometry, latlong_shape::geometry) AS geoms_3d_distance
FROM region_ids_for_latlong_shapes
WHERE ST_Distance(ST_GeogFromText('POINT(-118.46131 34.31171)'), latlong_shape) < 10

| geogs_intersect | geoms_intersect | geom_isvalid | relate_geoms | geogs_distance | geogs_no_spheroid_distance | geoms_distance          | geoms_3d_distance       |
| --------------- | --------------- | ------------ | ------------ | -------------- | -------------------------- | ----------------------- | ----------------------- |
| false           | true            | true         | 0FFFFF212    | 3.4064663      | 3.4146671                  | 0                       | 0                       |
| false           | false           | true         | FF0FFF212    | 5.63478588     | 5.64835122                 | 0.000054321999996886916 | 0.000054321999996886916 |
```

```sql
SELECT VERSION()

| version                                                                                                           |
| ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| PostgreSQL 13.9 on x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0, compiled by Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62), 64-bit |
```

```sql
SELECT PostGIS_Version();

| postgis_version                       |
| ------------------------------------- |
| 3.1 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1 |
```

For convenience, here is the GeoJSON that I visualized above. It contains the lookup point and the two closest polygons (as returned by `ST_AsGeoJSON`):

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -118.46131,
          34.31171
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -118.590173754,
              34.818203384
            ],
            [
              -118.554669477,
              34.818248424
            ],
            [
              -118.519233938,
              34.81833323
            ],
            [
              -118.500917157,
              34.818263939
            ],
            [
              -118.484492998,
              34.818255519
            ],
            [
              -118.466714818,
              34.818356235
            ],
            [
              -118.431575103,
              34.818707983
            ],
            [
              -118.413900556,
              34.818924424
            ],
            [
              -118.396521556,
              34.819207589
            ],
            [
              -118.375913258,
              34.819322959
            ],
            [
              -118.326206757,
              34.819675701
            ],
            [
              -118.298911338,
              34.819887117
            ],
            [
              -118.298911338,
              34.747356668
            ],
            [
              -118.30726467,
              34.747324674
            ],
            [
              -118.311221449,
              34.747259523
            ],
            [
              -118.315177432,
              34.747194256
            ],
            [
              -118.316156934,
              34.747178062
            ],
            [
              -118.31616929,
              34.747315306
            ],
            [
              -118.316271488,
              34.752065567
            ],
            [
              -118.312325229,
              34.752140489
            ],
            [
              -118.312326535,
              34.75219544
            ],
            [
              -118.312531114,
              34.760874375
            ],
            [
              -118.311419271,
              34.760887938
            ],
            [
              -118.311447254,
              34.761794819
            ],
            [
              -118.307547133,
              34.761876226
            ],
            [
              -118.307688072,
              34.76914709
            ],
            [
              -118.312139537,
              34.769051848
            ],
            [
              -118.312013231,
              34.761782985
            ],
            [
              -118.320871559,
              34.761596736
            ],
            [
              -118.320643006,
              34.751982309
            ],
            [
              -118.32518382,
              34.751892427
            ],
            [
              -118.325146684,
              34.750645594
            ],
            [
              -118.320698938,
              34.750725582
            ],
            [
              -118.320619613,
              34.747238796
            ],
            [
              -118.320621472,
              34.74711144
            ],
            [
              -118.319132498,
              34.74712522
            ],
            [
              -118.31912928,
              34.746989586
            ],
            [
              -118.318963759,
              34.742294886
            ],
            [
              -118.324094459,
              34.742214348
            ],
            [
              -118.324100254,
              34.742351721
            ],
            [
              -118.324765599,
              34.742340771
            ],
            [
              -118.324902701,
              34.742340774
            ],
            [
              -118.324782787,
              34.739791629
            ],
            [
              -118.324656399,
              34.739792562
            ],
            [
              -118.321818215,
              34.73983491
            ],
            [
              -118.321723743,
              34.737421328
            ],
            [
              -118.318794936,
              34.737463571
            ],
            [
              -118.318943061,
              34.741690458
            ],
            [
              -118.315014788,
              34.741751738
            ],
            [
              -118.314961133,
              34.739937086
            ],
            [
              -118.311042888,
              34.739996866
            ],
            [
              -118.311131734,
              34.743628911
            ],
            [
              -118.307195019,
              34.743692679
            ],
            [
              -118.307022176,
              34.73292151
            ],
            [
              -118.307017236,
              34.732701729
            ],
            [
              -118.306961869,
              34.729197417
            ],
            [
              -118.311327393,
              34.729174956
            ],
            [
              -118.311346965,
              34.732617423
            ],
            [
              -118.3113478,
              34.732644898
            ],
            [
              -118.311351901,
              34.732727164
            ],
            [
              -118.315711282,
              34.73267014
            ],
            [
              -118.315713308,
              34.732587934
            ],
            [
              -118.315701602,
              34.729152316
            ],
            [
              -118.320071884,
              34.729129528
            ],
            [
              -118.320062563,
              34.725505708
            ],
            [
              -118.315688277,
              34.725527134
            ],
            [
              -118.315674941,
              34.721907411
            ],
            [
              -118.320054027,
              34.721894246
            ],
            [
              -118.320044883,
              34.718366592
            ],
            [
              -118.320044698,
              34.71828416
            ],
            [
              -118.318949128,
              34.718285882
            ],
            [
              -118.317852726,
              34.718287568
            ],
            [
              -118.316757189,
              34.718289242
            ],
            [
              -118.315661616,
              34.718290466
            ],
            [
              -118.315591765,
              34.711052422
            ],
            [
              -118.31177053,
              34.711045178
            ],
            [
              -118.306851348,
              34.711035697
            ],
            [
              -118.306807821,
              34.703851184
            ],
            [
              -118.306807578,
              34.703768345
            ],
            [
              -118.311163994,
              34.703793557
            ],
            [
              -118.311164549,
              34.703710593
            ],
            [
              -118.311153205,
              34.700151308
            ],
            [
              -118.315521476,
              34.700168694
            ],
            [
              -118.315520836,
              34.698345595
            ],
            [
              -118.315520196,
              34.696522689
            ],
            [
              -118.315519752,
              34.694760206
            ],
            [
              -118.315519343,
              34.69294554
            ],
            [
              -118.315518911,
              34.691133595
            ],
            [
              -118.315518483,
              34.689349154
            ],
            [
              -118.315518511,
              34.689321676
            ],
            [
              -118.315518613,
              34.689225465
            ],
            [
              -118.324240593,
              34.6892215
            ],
            [
              -118.324199826,
              34.681929424
            ],
            [
              -118.324181765,
              34.678286336
            ],
            [
              -118.324013286,
              34.678286206
            ],
            [
              -118.321990626,
              34.678294268
            ],
            [
              -118.319802221,
              34.678302293
            ],
            [
              -118.319789286,
              34.676482105
            ],
            [
              -118.319776231,
              34.674800764
            ],
            [
              -118.319777068,
              34.674668997
            ],
            [
              -118.324156113,
              34.674640133
            ],
            [
              -118.324305833,
              34.667353292
            ],
            [
              -118.324299819,
              34.665534142
            ],
            [
              -118.324196404,
              34.665535338
            ],
            [
              -118.319819256,
              34.66554772
            ],
            [
              -118.319836703,
              34.661900053
            ],
            [
              -118.321427846,
              34.661592475
            ],
            [
              -118.322854394,
              34.661224449
            ],
            [
              -118.324355708,
              34.661602373
            ],
            [
              -118.324379145,
              34.660067608
            ],
            [
              -118.322436434,
              34.660073928
            ],
            [
              -118.320078162,
              34.66007227
            ],
            [
              -118.319016614,
              34.659630555
            ],
            [
              -118.318265028,
              34.659228426
            ],
            [
              -118.317204016,
              34.65892139
            ],
            [
              -118.316696353,
              34.658343507
            ],
            [
              -118.316433733,
              34.657886214
            ],
            [
              -118.316399174,
              34.657374451
            ],
            [
              -118.316233563,
              34.656701388
            ],
            [
              -118.315872914,
              34.656190468
            ],
            [
              -118.315317537,
              34.655922512
            ],
            [
              -118.314716272,
              34.655843026
            ],
            [
              -118.314152005,
              34.656042868
            ],
            [
              -118.313658715,
              34.656335886
            ],
            [
              -118.31325996,
              34.656463014
            ],
            [
              -118.312825923,
              34.656501405
            ],
            [
              -118.312240655,
              34.656360416
            ],
            [
              -118.311823758,
              34.656137014
            ],
            [
              -118.311295459,
              34.655640322
            ],
            [
              -118.310486705,
              34.655074199
            ],
            [
              -118.309612031,
              34.654525776
            ],
            [
              -118.308409437,
              34.654003693
            ],
            [
              -118.307518342,
              34.653679193
            ],
            [
              -118.306495295,
              34.653471832
            ],
            [
              -118.306491282,
              34.652731529
            ],
            [
              -118.306449169,
              34.645426711
            ],
            [
              -118.304251649,
              34.645432722
            ],
            [
              -118.302054126,
              34.645438694
            ],
            [
              -118.299868246,
              34.645445971
            ],
            [
              -118.298911338,
              34.645448524
            ],
            [
              -118.298911338,
              34.311655678
            ],
            [
              -118.590173754,
              34.311655678
            ],
            [
              -118.590173754,
              34.818203384
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -118.625390854,
              34.05061708
            ],
            [
              -118.625390854,
              34.311655678
            ],
            [
              -118.456022326,
              34.311655678
            ],
            [
              -118.456022326,
              34.05061708
            ],
            [
              -118.625390854,
              34.05061708
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Even if it were some great circle discrepancy, I'd expect the point to be intersecting one of the polygons, not outside both of them.

This is not always a valid assumption. This would work if the polygons had the same edge with exactly the same end points. But this is not the case, so each follows its own great circle. Here is the exaggerated version of what probably happens here, using two Geographies that would be perfectly aligned as Geometries (I used BigQuery GeoViz to draw this):

```
select 1 x, st_geogfromtext('polygon((20 20, 40 20, 40 40, 20 40, 20 20))') g1
union all
select 2, st_geogfromtext('polygon((25 40, 50 40, 50 60, 25 60, 25 40))')
```

As you can see, there is both overlap and a hole between two "rectangles" when the edges follow great circle.

[image: two near-rectangle as geographies]

Basically, you need to use the type (Geometry vs Geography) that really represents the shape you have. PostGIS does the right calculations, but when you cast to a different type, you may get wrong results.

If the reason you use Geometry is the lack of PostGIS ST_Subdivide for Geography type, consider making your own. I've created a ST_Subdivide version for BigQuery that works with Geography (BigQuery lacks Geometry type) - it should be possible to port it to PostGIS https://mentin.medium.com/subdivide-and-conquer-any-geometry-ca4f0a4b8491.

Comment: That must be it! I called `ST_Subdivide` with `geometry` (all it supports), and casted the `geometry` values to `geography`.

I'm wary of rolling my own `geography` version because I won't have all [the optimizations](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Subdivide.html#:~:text=Enhanced%3A%202.5.0%20reuses%20existing%20points%20on%20polygon%20split%2C%20vertex%20count%20is%20lowered%20from%208%20to%205.), as well as the edge cases you mention.

Seems like I need to wait for a `ST_Subdivide(geography, int)` implementation. For now, I'm calling `ST_Intersects` on the casted `geometry`. 